# Find common elements in Array of Lists

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have an array of Lists

```
List<testClass>[] input
```

from which I want to create output list

```
List<testClass>
```

`TestClass` has two fields - string `Name` and int `count`

For creating this output list, I want to compare every element of `testClass` in array with others and if there `Name` is same, I want to add their count and insert into output list. All other remaining unique `testClass` will be joined to output at the end.

Pseudo Code
For Ex: -

```
List<TestClass> L1 = [{"Google",2} ,{"Bing",7},{"Facebook",4},{"Instagram",10}]
List<TestClass> L2 = [{"Google",5} ,{"yahoo",1},{"Facebook",6},{"youtube",23}]
List<TestCLass> L3 = [{"youtube",12}]

//Input
List<TestClass> input[] = [L1,L2,L3]

//Output
List<TestClass> output = [{"Google",7},{"Bing",7},{"Facebook",10},{"Instagram",10},{"yahoo",1},{"youtube",35}]
```

The solution I can come up is only possible when the array size is fixed or only when two lists needs to be compared .

```
forEach(testClass e in L1)
{
   forEach(testClass f in L2)
   {
      if(e.Name == f.Name)
      {
        output. Add(new testClass (e.name,e.count+f.count))
      }
    }
}
```

Above code will fail on following condition

1. Array has more than 2 lists
2. Output List won't have testClass object whose value don't match

Comment: Well, you could add another loop  to iterate over the lists in the array, then the list and then the check list. You might want to create a set of names in the check list to speed that up. To solve issue no. 2 you might want to maintain an intermediate list of elements that have not been found in the check list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Rather than providing pseudo-code, it would be really helpful if you'd provide a [mcve] which we can use to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done easily with Linq.
You use the *SelectMany* method to flatten the array into a collection of items, the *GroupBy* method in order to group the collection's items by a property (in our case, the Name) and then, simply *Select* what you need from the grouped collection which is the name, and the sum of it's grouped values.

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Value { get; set; }

    public TestClass(string name, int val)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = val;
    }
}

List<TestClass> L1 = new List<TestClass>{ new TestClass("Google",2), new TestClass("Bing",7), new TestClass("Facebook",4),new TestClass("Instagram",10)};
List<TestClass> L2 = new List<TestClass>{ new TestClass("Google",5), new TestClass("yahoo",1) ,new TestClass("Facebook",6),new TestClass("youtube",23)};
List<TestClass> L3 = new List<TestClass>{ new TestClass("youtube",12)};

List<TestClass>[] input = new List<TestClass>[]{L1,L2,L3};

var output = input.SelectMany(arr => arr).GroupBy(item => item.Name).Select(grp => new TestClass(grp.Key, grp.Sum(item => item.Value))).ToList();

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output));
```

[Here is a .netFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/966V75)

Comment: how does it handle TestClass whose Name fields do not match? For Example TestClass("yahoo",1) is unique in all list. Group by will still include it?

Comment: The group collects items with the exact same key (meaning yahoo and Yahoo are different but yahoo and yahoo are the same). A group can contain one element as well. Check the .netFiddle that I've added to see the results and you can modify and test specific use cases online.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with LINQ.

SelectMany will flatten the array of lists into one stream of items.
Then the GroupBy groups then by Name and offers a result function to create a new item with the group key and the sum of all the counts.
Last we crreate a new list with the results.

```
var output = input.SelectMany(l => l)
    .GroupBy(t => t.Name, (name, e) => new testClass { Name = name, Count = e.Sum(x => x.Count) })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: You might want to explain this code so that new ones can easier understand what it does. In general, posting code without any explanation doesn't help others learn and I'd not consider this a good answer.